# Fillo dependency is not working for Maven project

Tags: java, excel, maven

i want to use to use Fillo for my maven project (on eclipse) to work with excel, so i did install the dependency.

but it is not working, it pops an error on console.
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL"

but when i ran the same code after importing fillo as external jar file in java project (on eclipse), it works perfectly.

I don't know what is the issue here, any suggestions?

Comment: can you show me your pom file? how you added the dependency.

Comment: <dependency>
  <groupId>com.codoid.products</groupId>
  <artifactId>fillo</artifactId>
  <version>1.17</version>
</dependency>          i added this dependency on pom file

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same issue and later i realized that it is related to the Fillo jar version compatibility with the Eclipse version compatibility.

**Fillo 1.16** worked with **Eclipse Mars**(Fillo 1.17 and 1.18 not worked on it)

**Fillo 1.17** and **1.18** worked with **Eclipse Oxygen**.

I hope this will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Fillo jar were conflicting with POI Jars.It worked after commenting out POI Jars in POM.XML.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue and later i realized that it is related to the Fillo jar version compatibility.

I used Fillo-1.21 and I changed that to Fillo-1.15.

Thats worked for me.